# How to remove Telerik UI for WPF localization?

Tags: wpf, localization, telerik

I would like to know if it's possible to make Visual Studio stop generating various folders (de, es, fr, it, nl, tr) containing Telerik resources dll localization files.

I know I could just manually/batch delete them, but I'd rather have them not generated at all. I have read the official documentation at http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/common-localization.html#Localization_Using_Custom_Localization_Manager , but couldn't find a clue on how to disable generating those folders and dll files.

Comment: Telerik told me no.  It does no harm keeping them there; just make sure you deploy properly.  They are not hurting anything.

Comment: They're a mess and I don't want them, it's absurd that I have to keep a bunch of files and folders which aren't needed.

Comment: You don't *have* to keep them. Delete them all and run your .exe, it will run fine.  Your best bet is to edit the project properties to run a delete files command for your post-build event.  The only other option I can think of is editing the Telerik source code to exclude all of the localized .resx files and getting it to rebuild.  That might be a long shot though.

Comment: I understand and I am using a batch file to relocate the generated files/folders, it's just that I wish I didn't have to do that only because the developers are stubborn enough not to give an option to turn off their export.